# Is :focus supposed to override :focus-visible styling?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, focus, accessibility

Is `:focus` styling supposed to override `:focus-visible`?

I am trying to make a site keyboard accessible and apply my own `:focus-visible` styling where possible.

My `:focus-visible` styling is successfully working with most of my button elements but is not working with my 'Log Out' button in which some twitter bootstrap `focus` styling is overriding my own `focus-visible` styling despite the bootstrap import statement being a lower priority.

How do I make `:focus-visible` styling higher priority than `:focus` styling?

**Update:**
Below is a link to a screenshot of the DevTools with the first 3 stylesheets listed being standard bootstrap found in the node_modules folder.
The 4th stylesheet is my own which attempts to just style the `:focus-visible` elements.
[Screenshot of Devtools summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsbFH.png)

HTML Button:

```
<button id="logOut" class="btn btn-dark btn-block mt-2" (click)="onLogout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Log out</button>
```

My CSS:

```css
:focus-visible {
    background-color: #143a84;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Bootstrap CSS:

```css
.btn-dark:focus, .btn-dark.focus {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    border-color: #c7c7c7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(195 196 197 / 50%);
}
```

Currently when I tab onto the button with the keyboard the bootstrap `focus` styling applies as opposed to the `:focus-visible` styling I have set.

Comment: :focus styling does not override :focus-visible.

Comment: @MeghnaBhuptani I didn't think it did from what I have read but then cannot work out why that is the case for this Log Out button. It cannot be a specificity issue as they should be completely unique stylings and I have checked to make sure that an `!important` isn't influencing it

Comment: Please provide a working code snippet.

Comment: Are you sure it is overriding and not that they are not using different properties than you are (e.g. you use `border` and they use `outline`). `:focus-visible` doesn't overwrite so `focus` styles will still be applied. If you can create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem I will happily show you how to fix it.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your comments. I have just added a screenshot of the devtools stylings for reference as I was unsure what code snippet would be most helpful.

Comment: Please provide a snippet. Can't able to fix the issue from the screenshot. Please provide sufficient information that which property you want to override for :focus and :focus-visible.

Comment: Sorry this is my first question on here so still unfamiliar with how to work stuff.

There should be code snippets up now.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-newton-v0mcqc?file=/src/styles.css

As per my understanding 
 :focus 

 :focus-visible   works like the same 

whichever style is last written will be applied to the element

Read this
https://css-tricks.com/the-focus-visible-trick/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code if you only want for `:focus-visible`. If you want for `:focus` also please add `#logOut.btn-dark:focus`

```css
#logOut.btn-dark:focus-visible {
    background-color: #143a84 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
        border-color: unset !important;
        box-shadow: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="logOut" class="btn btn-dark btn-block mt-2" (click)="onLogout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Log out</button>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with @Meghna's answer (thank you btw!) I have discovered that adding the following code snippet does achieve my goal of getting the button to display the `focus-visible` styling rather than the `focus` styling, however, I'm still unclear as to why the original did not work resulting in me needing this additional styling.

```
.btn-dark:focus-visible {
    background-color: #143a84;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I have been trying to avoid using `!important` where possible as it can make future styling difficult and is widely advised against in what I have read but thanks again for your answer.

I therefore now have a fix but it is more of a workaround rather than understanding the original root cause of the problem.

Comment: `.btn-dark:focus` is a more specific selector than `:focus-visible` because you're targeting `.btn` AND `:focus`. That's why you need `.btn-dark:focus-visible`. [Learn more about specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: @AmauryHanser Very true but as I understand it `:focus` and `:focus-visible` should be seperate entities, able to have their own unique styling and therefore their specificity levels shouldn't overlap :/

Comment: Well, if an element is `:focus-visible`, it also means that it is `:focus`, isn't it? That's how I understand it from the MDN doc.